# New Content in ASP.NET website without reloading the page

Tags: asp.net, web

I am trying to build a site with a "Next" button to display next question on the same page without reloading the page or redirecting to another page but I can't figure out how!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an UpdatePanel and a Scriptmanager.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <fieldset>

                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Question 1"></asp:Label>

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

            </fieldset>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in code behind just do what you always do

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Question 2";
}
```

You will find that the text of the label changes when the button is clicked without a page refresh.